# How to count suffixes in python?

Tags: python, string

I was working on a couple of things and first off I had to split a string (it was a paragaph) and then take off the punctuation of each string. For that I did the following:

```
a = string1.split()

print(a)

punc = "?.,!"

a = ["".join(c for c in s if c not in punc) for s in a]

print(a)
```

After this I have to count how many words end in "ing". I tried various ways but for some reason they always count 0 when they should count 10. This was my latest attempt:

```
suffix = "ing"

suffix_count = 0

if any (''.endswith(suffix) for s in a):

    suffix_count += 1

print ("Found {} words ending in ing".format(suffix_count))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
if any (''.endswith(suffix) for s in a):
    suffix_count += 1
```

try

```
suffix_count = sum(1 for s in a if s.endswith(suffix))
```

The issue with your code is that you're checking whether the empty string ends with 'suffix' (which is always false) but even if you got that check right: you're increasing suffix_count just once unrelated to how many strings end in 'suffix'.

Comment: @prpl.mnky.dshwshr Well, I hope the fact that we both point out the same issues is a hint that we're correct. ;-) For what it's worth, when I started writing my answer your answer did not address the fact that `suffix_count` was never incremented more than once. I see you added that now.

Comment: Thanks! This worked great. @prpl.mnky.dshwshr thanks for also explaining what I was doing wrong that helps a lot.

Comment: you could even just do `sum(s.endswith(suffix) for s in a)` (but your way is slightly faster probably)

Comment: @acushner More importantly, it's more readable. Sure, that way is shorter, but summing booleans is counter-intuitive. I'd always recommend the `sum(1 for a in b if c)` format for filtered counting.

Comment: i wouldn't say counter-intuitive (it's not like people don't expect summing up bools to work), i would say that people just don't usually think about that as an option. it's really useful if you have something in `numpy/pandas` like this trivial example: `(np.arange(10) > 6).sum()`. there are 3 numbers in that range greater than 6.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
suffix_count = len([s for s in a if s.endswith(suffix)])
```

Simply forms the list of all strings that end with the suffix, then computes the length of that list, which is of course the number of strings that ended with the suffix. I think it's cleaner than an explicit `for` loop.

Comment: This was [already mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28368169/567620) in another answer (just modified to allow for using a generator with `sum` instead of needing the interior comprehension in order to use `len`).

Comment: I really don't think the two expressions are the same.

Comment: Well, we can disagree, but in the older version of that answer, this exact code with the comprehension was used, and it was later modified to instead work with a generator to avoid needing the comprehension.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe Gaah, that's right, I had a typo. Fixed, I hope. Thanks.

Comment: No I think you can't put the `if` part in front of the `for`, you need the `if` at the end.

Comment: @prpl.mnky.dshwshr Yeah, that's fixed too. Thanks.

Comment: This creates a list of all the matching values just to throw it away, not really optimal memory-wise, and less readable than using `sum()`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a much easier way to remove punc and sum using `rstrip` so we don't need to loop over every char:

```
sum(s.rstrip(punc).endswith("ing") for s in a)
```

So your double loop can be replaced with the following to  remove the punc:

```
a = [s.rstrip(punc) for s in a]
```

Also using `string.punctuation` may be better:

```
from string import punctuation
a = [s.rstrip(punctuation) for s in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

```
a = ["singing", "dancing", "playing"]

suffix = "ing"

suffix_count = 0

for s in a:
    if s.endswith(suffix):
        suffix_count += 1

print ("Found {} words ending in ing".format(suffix_count))
```

For me it printed 3.

Hope it helps